# Different number of posts showing in development vs production server

Tags: wp-query, loop, wp-reset-query

So I'm working on a website for a client. Everything works fine except for the fact that the number of posts showing in the homepage of my development server is different from the number of posts showing in the production server.

Here's my query:

```
      <?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 4 );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
      ?>
        <div class="mini-post col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <h3><?php $title = the_title('','',false); echo wp_trim_words( $title, 8, null ); ?></h3>
            <p class="date"><?php the_time( 'F j, Y' ); ?></p>
          </a>
        </div> <!-- .mini-post -->
      <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

As you can see, I'm limiting the number of posts to 4. And it works [here](http://fundacionzt.yunke.com.pa/)

However, in my live [website](http://fundacionzt.org/), it's showing 6!

I've tried writing the query in different ways and still get the same result.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: If something is overriding your query arguments, you have a filter somewhere modifying the query.

Comment: Are any of the posts sticky? See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99697/21376

Comment: @s_ha_dum had the correct answer. I had some sticky posts messing up my post count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @s_ha_dum, I had some sticky posts. I had to use the

```
'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
```

argument inside the `WP_Query`.